# Display a box with contents in Iphone View

Tags: iphone

I am working on an app which displays user information on the home view. Its a regular tab bar application, which brings up the home view on load. I need to display something like,

Hello Joe,

Your current points are : xxx

I would like this to be in a white curved background box. (The background for the view is blue). Is there something like a UIPanel or something like that. I would really like to avoid having another view or a webView, not sure if thats going to affect the speed of loading the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there were a UIPanel control it would derive from UIView, so I'm not sure why you want to avoid another view.  If I'm understanding you, it sounds like you want a custom alert window of some sort.  You could just use the UIAlertView control to display your message, but if you are dead set on a custom look, then you will need to use a view.

This shouldn't affect performance noticeably if you are just displaying some text with maybe a button on a custom image.  Especially if this is just a tab bar application with nothing too crazy happening in the background (animations, etc.).

I would suggest creating a View either in code (this will be slightly faster, but once again probably not noticeably so) or with Interface Builder that has a black background with an opacity of like .2-.5 and on that view adding a UIImageView set to your custom image (a png of a white curved box with transparent corners).  Then put a UILabel with your text and a button to dismiss it.

On load just instantiate the above view and add it to your current view.  It will show your message modally.  Then capture the button tap event to have it remove itself from it's superview.

There are plenty of examples of how to do exactly this out there and there are even other ways of doing it than what I've suggested.  If you need further assistance let me know.

Comment: I think what you suggested is great. I don't want it as a modal pop up or alert view though, it will be part of the screen. Can I still do it with another view.. how will it work, will it overlap with the existing home view, or as you said, just have an image on the existing view with a white background etc, and have labels on top of it.. that should do it. I did not know that I could place labels on top of images. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you don't need the modal part, it will be even easier.  Just add the UIImageView with your custom background and put the label on top (directly on your home view).  This is very easy to do with Interface Builder (drag and drop) on your existing xib file.  But you can also do it in code pretty easy (just adjust the frame origin of the image/label to position them where you want).

Comment: Thank you very much. Thats exactly what I wanted. I just didn't think of UIImageview and having labels on top of it. Thanks again.

Comment: This does not seem to work as the label does not show up in the view if put on top of the imageview.

Comment: Just in case if someone is looking for the same, i figured it out in another way. Just had a background image with the white rounded corner image as part of it, aligned the labels on top of the background image.. initially i was trying to put a separate UIImageView but it was hiding the labels etc.